# How do you convert a string holding a date from DD-MM-YYYY to MM-DD-YYYY

Tags: arrays, c++11

I have been working on this for about a week and for some reason I just can't get past it. I am getting an out of range error when I am searching the elements of the array, and attempt to move the characters I need to a need array.

void showFileDateCleansed(string first[], string last[], string birthday[])
{

```
string tempHoldDD[10];
string tempHoldMM[10];
/*
The stuff below is working so  Ijust commented it out until I figure out the isssue I am having with the dates
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
first[i].at(0) = toupper(first[i].at(0));
last[i].at(0) = toupper(last[i].at(0));
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
cout << first[i] << " ";
cout << last[i] << "\n";
}*/

int d = 0; //Im using this to keep track of whether I have passed the delimiter in the text file "-"
bool done = false;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{

    done = false;
    int c = 0;//this is used for the character within the element of the array, it increments at the bottom so that it moves to the next character.

    while (done != true)
    {

        // <TK> Check for invalid character
        if (c == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid character at index: " << i << std::endl;

        }

        if (birthday[i].at(c) == '-')
        {
            d += 1;
            done = true;
        }
        else
        {
            switch (d)
            {
            case 0:
            {

                //  Try catch to prevent the out of range exception from crashing.
                //try
                //{
                    //  Debug
                    std::cout << "C: " << c << std::endl;

                    // create a temporary variable for the value.
                    char temp = birthday[i].at(c);
                    tempHoldDD[i].at(c) = temp;
                //}
                /*catch (std::out_of_range const& exc)
                {
                    std::cout << exc.what() << '\n';
                }*/

                //cout << tempHoldMM[c] << "\n";

            }

            case 1:
            {
                // Try catch to prevent the out of range exception from crashing.
                try
                {
                    // Debug
                    std::cout << "C: " << c << std::endl;

                    // create a temporary variable for the value.
                    char temp = tempHoldMM[i].at(c);
                    birthday[i].at(c) = temp;
                }
                catch (std::out_of_range const& exc)
                {
                    std::cout << exc.what() << '\n';
                }

                //cout << tempHoldMM[c] << "\n";
                c += 1;
                break;
            }


            }



        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `case 1` in your `switch` statement doesn't have a `break` statement, so it will fall through to `case 2`, where `c` is incremented. Could that make `c` get out of range too fast?

Comment: No It was doing it before. I meant to put the break back in. I've just been tearing it apart trying to figure out whats going on. I probably should have cleaned it up a bit.

Comment: It break at tempHoldDD[i].at(c) = temp in case 0.

Comment: Why are you operating on arrays of strings? That statement that's breaking says "set the `c`-th character of the `i`-th string in `tempHoldDD` to `temp`."  Since your date strings are 10 characters long I can't help but think you're thinking incorrectly about your data. Just one string is an array of characters.

Comment: It's for school, that's how they wanted it done. I'm trying to grab the day portions of the date and store them in an array, then do the same with the months. After that I am going to rebuild that dates in the proper format.